# In which regional dialects is "I'm sat" common?

Tags: british-english, dialects

I had always associated the construct *I'm sat here* (as opposed to *I'm sitting here*) with the north of England. I know I've heard it from people with Yorkshire or Manchester accents, for example. Yet, I was recently speaking with a couple of Londoners, one of whom used it and the other stated it sounded natural.

Here are some examples I found in [Google Books](https://www.google.gr/search?q=%22i%27m%20sat%20here%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=_uN_V_GdFYfWUe6Zt_gF) to clarify the specific usage I am referring to:

> Don't think: I'm sat here waiting for my plays to be produced; think: I am sat here waiting to write those plays that can only be produced, now. [[source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=j8s0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT147&dq=%22i%27m+sat+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpdzhs-bNAhWIzRQKHVlTCnEQ6AEIKjAC)]
>
> I'm sat here in Vittles waiting for a second pot of tea, and life is OK, on the whole. [[source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=zRmPPCsoy_YC&pg=PA79&dq=%22i%27m+sat+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpdzhs-bNAhWIzRQKHVlTCnEQ6AEIMDAD)]
>
> I'm sat here, in the back of a van with my Thermos full of hot tea, protecting a car-park. [[source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=-ATXNsYkT80C&pg=PA1&dq=%22i%27m+sat+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpdzhs-bNAhWIzRQKHVlTCnEQ6AEINjAE)]
>
> And it'sonly now that I'm sat here to with Emma that the absurdity of what I'm doing is starting hit home. [[source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=EW8mAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT163&dq=%22i%27m+sat+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpdzhs-bNAhWIzRQKHVlTCnEQ6AEIPDAF)]
>
> I'm sat here watching and listening to them talk. [[source](https://books.google.gr/books?id=wbf-AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=%22i%27m+sat+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpdzhs-bNAhWIzRQKHVlTCnEQ6AEIeTAQ)]

So, how common is this in the UK? Is it actually regional and, if so, of which region, or is it a more widespread expression?

Comment: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sit) has a usage note that says, “Originally only in dialect, it is now common in British (though not US) English”.

Comment: I don't think "I'm sat here" means "I'm sitting here" - I think it means "I'm to be seated here" or "I will be sittling here". You'd only say it if the chair was empty (perhaps you got up to feed the dog). It reminds me of the recent question on Western Pa. dialect "dog wants fed" and "clothes need washed".

Comment: @PhilSweet You're confusing two different usages. The usage this question is about is specifically about the more rare - but still common - UK usage, and it definitely does mean "I'm sitting here".

Comment: It's also not rare _at all_. I move to the UK a few years after posting this question and I can confirm I hear it all the time. Probably more often than _I'm sitting here_.

Comment: See also [difference between I'm sat and I'm sitting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336376/is-there-any-difference-between-im-sat-and-im-sitting)

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_grammatical_differences)

> In [British English], the word *sat* is often colloquially used to cover *sat, sitting* and *seated*: *I've been sat here waiting for half an hour. The bride's family will be sat on the right-hand side of the church.* That construction is not often heard outside the UK. **In the 1960s, its use would mark a speaker as coming from Northern England, but by the turn of the 21st century, it had spread to the Southern England.** Its use often conveys lighthearted informality in which many speakers intentionally use a dialect or colloquial construction they would probably not use in formal written English. The colloquial usage is widely understood by British speakers. Similarly, *stood* may be used instead of *standing.* To Americans and still to many Britons, those usages are passive and may imply that the subject had been involuntarily forced to sit or to stand or directed to hold that location.

Comment: Any sources given? I moved to the UK a few months after asking this and now have significantly more experience with this formulation and its use in London, southern England. As far as I can tell it is both ubiquitous and used entirely seriously, with no implied lightheartedness. It seems to have become standard.

Answer (score 1):

I had a welsh friend in primary school who would say this often. We live in New Zealand, so I don't know many people who speak with other British dialects, I couldn't compare them.