# Why do people say 'sat'?

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms, contemporary-english

A while ago, I think, I started hearing and reading people use the verb 'to sit' incorrectly, but it seems to becoming increasingly common.

Such as "I am sat", "We are sat", "They were sat". Sit is a pretty regular verb. The perfect form of it (sat) is the only irregular form of it, so it makes this doubly odd.

For instance:
[Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/p/how-to-apply-to-go-on-gogglebox-because-whose-family-isnt-comedy-gold-15986872)

> Never is this more literal than when you are sat in front of the telly watching Gogglebox.

[Cher concert booking](https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/whats-on/music-nightlife-news/live-cher-tour-tickets-sale-15550323)

> Wondering where you will be sat?

[Mirror.co.uk](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/first-picture-18-year-old-11105131)

> Feels like yesterday we was sat in college moaning to finish

Could this error be deliberate, as a form of inverse snobbery (attempting to appear mainstream)? This might also be a particularly British thing, rather than American. Certainly all the examples I can see online seem to be from British (typically colloquial) sources.

Comment: "Sat" is not only the past tense, but also the past participle of "sit". The participle is what's being used here. Compare "I am located at..." or "It is positioned at...".

Comment: not standard English, and I do not think I have ever run across it in AmE, even in a known slang usage.

Comment: Dupe of this -  [Is "I am sat" bad English?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english), as @sumelic has pointed out.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate target, you might also find the answers to [Is there any difference between “I'm sat” and “I'm sitting”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/336376/177853) interesting.