# You'll be sat in this flat

Tags: grammar

In an English dram "Under Her Eyes" there's a conversation as follows between two women:

> Adam(your son) will be grown up and gone and living his own life somewhere.
> And you’ll be sat in this flat, still only in your forties.

Is **"you'll be sat in this flat"** grammatically correct and commonly used? **"You'll be sitting in this flat"** seems to be more usual to me.

Comment: [Look at this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336263/in-which-regional-dialects-is-im-sat-common), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336376/is-there-any-difference-between-im-sat-and-im-sitting), and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english) - it's regional dialect from northern England.

Comment: Please proof read your question, I assume it's a drama not a dram. And direct quotations should go either in quotation marks or be indented.

Comment: I've commented elsewhere that my friend and I have a standing joke that, when someone says "I was sat [somewhere]", we can both hear our late mothers say sternly "**Sitting!**" But the usage is becoming increasingly common.